# NGINX rewrite for vanity URLs when file doesn't exist (try_files and rewrite together)

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I'm trying to get vanity URLs on my server. If the file path from the URL doesn't exist, I want to rewrite the URL to profile.php, but if my users have periods in their usernames, their vanity URL doesn't work.

Here is my conf block.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.example.com;

    rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)$ /profile.php?url=$1 last;

    root   /var/www/html/example.com;
    error_page 404 = /404.php;

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        expires 1y;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass  example_fast_cgi;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /var/www/html/example.com$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    location / {
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }

    location /404.php {
        internal;
        return 404;
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably use `try_files` and `@LOCATION`. Something like this (simplified, untested example):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;

    root /var/www/html/example.com;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files /$uri @PROFILEALIAS;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass example_fast_cgi;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location @PROFILEALIAS {
        fastcgi_pass example_fast_cgi;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/profile.php;
        fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING url=$uri;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

The trick with `try_files` is to avoid sending requests for static files to PHP as profile pages. Similar thing can be accomplished with regex locations, but this is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a period `\.` to the regex, if it's meant to be valid in a user name.

But the best approach is to handle these within your application using the front controller pattern, like many other popular web applications do.